connect in websocket using VPS and nginx
server {
    server_name scitrack.online www.scitrack.online;

    root /home/scitrack/SciTrack;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # PHP handling (if needed)
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/scitrack.online.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/scitrack.online.error.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/scitrack.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/scitrack.online/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


}

server {
    if ($host = www.scitrack.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = scitrack.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name scitrack.online www.scitrack.online;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/scitrack.online configuration.
this is the error in my website
I already have created another configuration file named wss.scitrack.online with an SSL and this is the code block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wss.scitrack.online;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/scitrack.online/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/scitrack.online/privkey.pem;

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wss.scitrack.online;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

this is my javascript websocket connection
I have also tried to connect in my javascript on this domain 'wss://wss.scitrack.online:9000/ws/' and got the same error
PS: I am using ratchet websocket
